# Understanding parameter 'e' and e.pageX/e.pageY

Tags: jquery

```
function smtMouseMove(e){
    smtMouseCoordsX=e.pageX;
    smtMouseCoordsY=e.pageY;
    smtTipPosition();
}

function smtTipPosition(e){
    var thePosX=e.pageX+20;
    smtTip.css("left",thePosX);

    var thePosY=smtMouseCoordsY+20;
    smtTip.css("top",thePosY);

}
```

If I have this: `var thePosX=e.pageX+20;` I gat the error that parameter e is undefined. But if I write `var thePosX=smtMouseCoordsX+20;` everything is ok. What do I miss in  here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your function declaration, you are asking a parameter `e` to be sent.

```
function smtTipPosition(e) {}
```

But, you are **not** sending the parameter on your execution.

```
function smtMouseMove(e){
    smtMouseCoordsX=e.pageX;
    smtMouseCoordsY=e.pageY;
    smtTipPosition();
               // ^ Right here, you have to send the parameter 'e' too
}
```

Implementing something like this, should *fix the problem.*

```
function smtMouseMove(e){
    smtTipPosition(e);
}

function smtTipPosition(e){
    var thePosX=e.pageX+20;
    smtTip.css("left",thePosX);

    var thePosY=smtMouseCoordsY+20;
    smtTip.css("top",thePosY);

}
```

Generally, `e` refers to an ***event object***. It has to be initiated or passed on by some event or function. On you case also, function `setMouseMove` and `smtTipPosition` both require a event object for its execution.

Lets see a simple example

```
$("a").click(function(e) {
    //Here `e` will hold the event object of the page, when any `a` on the page will be clicked
    console.log(e.pageX); //Calling this will give the x coordinates of mouse position on the page, when the `a` was clicked
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`e` is to a event object, event object is associated with methods or events (such as onmouseover, onmousout events ) .

you are missing the parameter `smtTipPosition();` function. either pass the event object, or send the position values to smtTipPosition() function

```
function smtMouseMove(e){
    smtMouseCoordsX=e.pageX;
    smtMouseCoordsY=e.pageY;
    smtTipPosition(smtMouseCoordsX,smtMouseCoordsy);
}
```

Set the css with Position, with Parameterized values.

```
function smtTipPosition(posX, PosY){
    var thePosX=posX+20;
    smtTip.css("left",thePosX);

    var thePosY=PosY+20;
    smtTip.css("top",thePosY);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others already said you've to pass the mouse position to the second method as follows:

```
function smtMouseMove(e){
    smtTipPosition({ x: e.pageX, y: e.pageY });
}

function smtTipPosition(point) {
    smtTip.css("left", e.x + 20);
    smtTip.css("top", e.y + 20);
}
```